# Terraform lists in version 0.12+

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am upgrading from terraform 0.11.4 to 0.12.2. I have straightened out most of the stuff by following [this guide](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html) but I can't seem to find a solution for the following list expression.

```
variable "subnetIds" {
  type = "list"
}

resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name            = "myload-balancer"
  subnets         = ["${var.subnetIds}"] # <-- problem row
  security_groups = ["${var.securityGroupIds}"]
}
```

The error message is:

```
  on main.tf line 10, in resource "aws_lb" "main":
  10:   subnets         = ["${var.subnetIds}"]

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": element 0: string required.
```

If I remove the brackets `[]` I get the following error:

```
  on main.tf line 10, in resource "aws_lb" "main":
  10:   subnets         = "${var.subnetIds}"

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": incorrect set element type:
string required.
```

What is the correct way to express `subnets` for resource `aws_lb` using terraform 0.12+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you do not show a typical value for `var.securityGroupIds` and `var.subnetIds`, I will assume they are both lists. In Terraform < 0.12, you were required sometimes to put redundant array notation for parameter arguments and did not have first class support for variables. In Terraform >= 0.12, you should no longer put redundant array notation and you do have first class support for variables. You can update your code to handle both via:

```
resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name            = "myload-balancer"
  subnets         = var.subnetIds
  security_groups = var.securityGroupIds
}
```

Thus the redundant `[]` are removed and the unnecessary string interpolation is also removed.

Comment: Thanks, well – the subnetIds and securityGroupIds are both lists. When I remove the brackets, with or without quotes, the output is as the second error message in the question i.e. 

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": incorrect set element type:
string required.

Comment: Found the answers and I got the inspiration from this answer so I'll mark this as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. The `subnetIds` were passed from the output of a previous layer (remote state).

```
subnetIds = ["${data.terraform_remote_state.eventsource.outputs.subnetIds}"]
```

Basically this means that the `subnetIds` variable became a list of lists.

After changing to this it all works:

```
subnetIds = data.terraform_remote_state.eventsource.outputs.subnetIds
```